# How do I install Windows, if Ubuntu is my only Operating System?

Tags: windows

I have had Windows 8 on my Acer Aspire One 722 netbook for several months now dualbooting with Ubuntu 12.04 but due to a recent booting problem(bad_system_config to be exact) I formatted  the partition containing windows and I want to reinstall it. I have already bought it(duh!) And I have the product key but no version of windows is currently on the system only Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: That doesnt help me reinstall windows does it?

Comment: Just install Windows on the same partition then repair Grub after words

Comment: No i need to know how to do that because when i installed it first time i did so via the upgrade assistant which is a windows only application

Comment: by 'it' I assume you mean ubuntu, since the laptop would have shipped with windows already on it? so you have never installed windows by booting off a windows disk? that is the standard process. just put in your windows disk, and reboot (perhaps configuring the bios). or is the issue that the only disk you have is a acer restore disk, which wants to partition the whole drive? to be clear you should be able to install linux or windows from disk regardless of what OS is (if any at all) on the system.

Comment: No by it i mean windows

Comment: I havent got a installation disk. It was a diwnload.

Comment: then you need to contact Acer for restore media, or otherwise get a windows disk. since you've got your key, any old disk win8 should work.

Comment: I cant because the warranty is out of date its two years old, anyway i bought the windows 8 from Microsoft. It came with Windows 7 pre installed

Comment: then you will need to get some windows disk (can be win7) to install and upgrade from, since the digital distribution is usually a self-executing archive, rather than a disk image or other more boot friendly package. you may also be able to execute the installer while booted from a BartPE disk. Also, don't be so sure Acer won't give you disks. they usually charge 15-20$ for them anyway, so it wouldn't make sense to deny you the right to purchase one just because the warranty is elapsed.

Comment: Ok thanks but if i bought the laptop with an operating system installed why do they charge for the recovery disc. Isnt it the buyers right to get the disc free

Comment: So whats the answer

Comment: capitalism? you want me to tell you why a company made a choice that puts their profits first? at best, I can say each company makes their own choices for their own reasons, and no one here is privy to them. There is no other answer we can give you other than that you need to obtain a disk, however it is you choose to do that.

Comment: Thanks will be doing that unless i deploy it some other way.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the BIOS settings to have your computer boot from the Windows 8 disc and during installation select the now empty partition as windows 8's root directory.

Afterwards, in order to be able to use your Ubuntu installation, you will have to recover GRUB2:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2